# Webpack replace content between html comment tags

Tags: javascript, webpack

How can i replace

```
<!-- vendors.js - Start -->
<script src="../node_modules/lodash/index.js"></script>
<script src="../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script> <!--Replace with min.js-->
<script src="../node_modules/jquery-ui/ui/core.js"></script>
<script src="../node_modules/jquery-ui/ui/widget.js"></script>
<script src="../node_modules/jquery-ui/ui/mouse.js"></script>
<script src="../node_modules/jquery-ui/ui/sortable.js"></script>
<script src="../node_modules/angular/angular.js"></script>
<script src="../node_modules/angular-animate/angular-animate.js"></script>
<!-- vendors.js - End -->
```

with

```
<script src="vendors.js"></script>
```

while `webpack` bundling ?

Can this be achieve using `html-replace-webpack-plugin` ?

Answer (score 1):

All of the libraries you have listed are available on https://unpkg.com/.

- https://unpkg.com/lodash@4.17.15/lodash.min.js
- https://unpkg.com/jquery@3.4.1/dist/jquery.min.js
- https://unpkg.com/jquery-ui@1.12.1/ui/core.js
- https://unpkg.com/jquery-ui@1.12.1/ui/widget.js
- https://unpkg.com/jquery-ui@1.12.1/ui/widgets/mouse.js
- https://unpkg.com/jquery-ui@1.12.1/ui/widgets/sortable.js
- https://unpkg.com/angular@1.7.8/angular.min.js
- https://unpkg.com/angular-animate@1.7.8/angular-animate.min.js

My suggestion is to use: https://www.npmjs.com/package/webpack-cdn-inject and inject these dependencies into your HTML document(s) vs. trying to bundle them and add to your build times.